# Safek De'Oraysa Le'Chumra

Tags: halacha-theory, safek, deorayta

The classic example of safek de'oraysa le'chumra is when there is an agreement that a de'oraysa exists but there is a debate as to which cases constitute the de'oraysa. In such a debate we paskin le'chumra.

I would like to know about a debate whether a de'oraysa exists altogether or not. Would we say here safek de'oraysa lechumra and paskin that the de'oraysa exists?

My question (essentially) questions what "safek de'oraysa" means. What cases of "safek de'oraysa" do we pasken like the machmir position?

Just to spell it out a little more, I know we say "safek within an already established de'oraysa" lechumrah, but do we say "safek whether there is a de'oraysa or not" lechumrah?

Comment: "Would we say here safek de'oraysa lechumra and paskin that the de'oraysa exists?" I don't see why saying safek de'oraysa lechumra implies that we must paskin that the de'orays exists.

Comment: @DoubleAA I edited my question to explain why (linguistically) I have this question.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this issue is the crux of the difference between Ashkenazi and Sephardi theology. Ashkenazim hold that it is a Deorita mitzva to go stringent in a case of doubt, Serphardim hold it is a derabannan.

Comment: @ClintEastwood, hard to imagine that it has such theological implications. There are about 4-5 cases (maybe more) that the Rambam et. al. would admit are Torah matters - there is such a thing as an Asham Taluy after all.

Comment: If there are three pieces of meat and it is known that one is not kosher, an ashkenazi may eat two of the pieces and the final piece is considered the non kosher one, but for a sephardi, all of the meat is considered kosher.

Comment: What I think you're talking about is ikva isura and lo ikva isura. Ikva isura is when there's definitely an issur, like there was chelev (which is not Kosher fat) and shomen (kosher fats), and you ate one of them. Lo ikva isura is, for example, there's only one thing, and you ate it, and you're not sure if it's chelev and shomen. Shev Shmatsa (I think it was written by the K'tzos), in Shmata Alef, discusses this topic, and I'm 99%sure he discusses what you're asking about. I could look it up over Shabbos.

Answer (score 3):

There is a dispute as to whether beracha me'ein shalosh (al hamichiya etc.) is rabbinic or Biblical.  Some Rishonim, for example the Rashba, hold it is Biblical, while others, for example the Rambam, hold it is Rabbinic.  So there is a halachic safek about the existence of a Biblical requirement to make a beracha acharona of me'ein shalosh.

The Magen Avraham (O.C. 172:3) is stringent, against the normal rule of safek berachos lehakel, based on this safek.  He seems to deal with it as a safek d'oraisa l'chumra.

Comment: Hmm, maybe he paskens like the Rashba?

Comment: Isn't this the first case? We know there is a Deorayta to Bentch, we just don't know if mezonos counts as (sufficiently) bread(-like).

Comment: @Yishai he cites it as a יש אומרים.  Doesn't seem to be paskening definitively that way.

Comment: @DoubleAA No - the machlokes about mezonos is not if it is bread.  The machlokes is about all shivas haminim, and is about how to read the psukim.  See the Rashba on berachos 35a.

Comment: @YEZ I don't mean conceptually "bread" just something that requires Bentching (I know that's circular). I just mean "there is a debate as to which cases constitute the de'oraysa" so it's the first case, no?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I understood the question to be about a sofek of the Din vs. a sofek of the Metziyus.

Comment: @DoubleAA It is a case where there is a doubt as to whether or not the de'oraysa exists.  It is not "I know there is a mitzva to make a beracha acharona on mezonos et. al, is this that?"  It is a case of "Is there a mitzva to do X.  If so, this is definitely it."  I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I thought he was asking about something like Tevilat Keilim where it's not clear there is any Deorayta at all. Would SDlCh lead us to paskin like those Rishonim who think it does exist? @Yishai YEZ